# Convert unicode URL to ASCII

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, ascii

I'm writing a PHP application that accepts an URL from the user, and then processes it with by making some calls to binaries with `system()`*. However, to avoid many complications that arise with this, I'm trying to convert the URL, which may contain Unicode characters, into ASCII characters.

Let's say I have the following URL:

```
https://täst.de:8118/news/zh-cn/新闻动态/2015/
```

Here two parts need to be dealt with: the hostname and the path.

- For the hostname, I can simply call `idn_to_ascii()`.
- However, I can't simply call `urlencode()` over the path, as each of the characters that need to remain unmodified will also be converted (e.g. `news/zh-cn/新闻动态/2015/ -> news%2Fzh-cn%2F%E6%96%B0%E9%97%BB%E5%8A%A8%E6%80%81%2F2015%2F` as opposed to `news/zh-cn/%E6%96%B0%E9%97%BB%E5%8A%A8%E6%80%81/2015/`).

How should I approach this problem?

---

<sup>*I'd rather not deal with `system()` calls and the resulting complexity, but given that the functionality is only available by calling binaries, I unfortunately have no choice.</sup>

Comment: Could you split it at the slashes, run urlencode() in a loop on each element, then join it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following can be used for this transformation:

```
function convertpath ($path) {
  $path1 = '';
  $len = strlen ($path);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
     if (preg_match ('/^[A-Za-z0-9\/?=+%_.~-]$/', $path[$i])) {
       $path1 .= $path[$i];
     }
     else {
       $path1 .= urlencode ($path[$i]);
     }
  }
  return $path1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

split URL by `/` then `urlencode()` that part then put it back together

```
$url = explode("/", $url);
$url[2] = idn_to_ascii($url[2]);
$url[5] = urlencode($url[5]);
$url = join("/", $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function:

```
inconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $url);
```